# Why setbuf crashes with open_memstream file?

Tags: posix, stdio

I'm playing with "new"  stdio functions mentioned in c11 standard:`open_memstream` and `fmemopen`.

Compiling on Ubuntu 16.10 with gcc or on Rextester with clang (see link below)

```
size_t sizeloc = 0; char *bufloc = NULL;
FILE *mf = open_memstream (&bufloc, &sizeloc);
setbuf(mf, NULL);  // this crashes
```

Calling setbuf for unbuffered mode on a file created with **open_memstream** throws sigsegv. (I'm wanting to set unbuffered mode rather than call `fflush` after every write. By the way, fflush works.)

Why setbuf(mf, NULL) crashes? What I'm doing wrong?

On a file returned by the other function,  **fmemopen**,  `setbuf(mf, NULL)` works and seems to do what expected.

[link to my example @rextester](http://rextester.com/PALR79235)

Comment: I don't know where you get this from, but both functions are definitively not C11. They are POSIX 2008, and not supported on other systems, I think. So they have not much to do with neither C99 nor C11. I remove these flags and add POSIX.

Comment: Trying to change the buffering behavior of a function that entirely works in memory sounds weird. Don't you think that the provider of your implementation has already optimized that as far as possible? Changing buffering of files that correspond to devices makes sense because these can be slow (latency or throughput), but here this makes none. In addition, you only can access the resulting buffer after a `fflush`, anyhow.

Comment: Thank you Jens. Actually what I expected that  these memory mapped streams are unbuffered and their backing memory immediately contains result of last write. But it is not the case. A flush is needed. This is why I tried to set unbuffered mode, and it seems to work with one of these.

Comment: @JensGustedt - I stand corrected, this is not c11, I've found it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, what you are trying to do is not currently supported by POSIX.  It is also unnecessary because the specification for `open_memstream` essentially says that there is no buffering (at least I think that is the intent).

It appears both `open_memstream` and `fmemopen` were added to POSIX without considering the interaction with existing interfaces.  The description of `setvbuf` has been copied from the C standard and has not updated and says:

> The *setvbuf()* function may be used after the stream pointed to by *stream* is associated with an open file but before any other operation […]

That implies that using this function for the new streams would not be allowed because there is no associated file.  But I think this is really an accident, and the interaction with `open_memstream` and `fmemopen` was simply missed.  The same thing happened on the implementation side, where this use case was not considered, either, so glibc crashes here.

Similarly, it's not clear whether `fflush (NULL)` should have an impact on streams which are not file-backed.

Comment: Florian. In my example I did fflush on the FILE descriptor of both kinds of "memory files" and it works (before calling fflush the backing memory is empty, after fflush it contains what expected). But the point is I want to avoid. calling fflush.

Comment: Ah, interesting use case. Do you want to make sure that the pointer and size value you passed to `open_memstream` are always current with respect to what was written to the buffer?

Comment: Yes if possible.

Comment: I think the intent of the POSIX specification for `open_memstream` is that it is unbuffered. I haven't checked yet whether the glibc implementation complies with that (I have some doubts about the null terminator).

Comment: " I think the intent of the POSIX specification for open_memstream is that it is unbuffered"   - I hoped so, but on my Ubuntu it is buffered. Until calling fflush or closing the stream, content of the memory will not update. I can live with this if there's no quick obvious 'fix'.